# using Rijndael with MFC VS 2013

Tags: c++, encryption, mfc, rijndael

I'm building an MFC application with VS 2013 for Encryption and Decryption using AES , and I'm using Rijndael c++ implementation .
the problem is After adding Rijndeal.cpp and .h to the project and make a compilation  i get this error

error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'rijndael.h': No such file or directory

anyone have an idea how to solve that ?

Comment: Check the file name and/or the name specified in include. I believe you have got a typo.

Comment: Either you have a typo or there is not enough information to help you.

Comment: Maybe VS can't find the include directory. Try adding relative path, `include "something\Rijndael.h"`, or go to menu -> project -> properties -> C/C++ -> additional include directories.